# Azure Cloud Services Extended Support Deploy using New-AzCloudService powershell. Set swappable cloud service

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cloud-services

Few days ago I moved my service from Azure Cloud Services **classic** to Cloud Services **extended support**. The latest doesn't have Production/Staging slots. There is a new swap mechanism that is activated if during a deploy we configured the "swappable cloud service". I can do it using Visual Studio publish magic and it works fine.

Now I want to make a deploy using powershell script. The code below just creates a new deploy without activated swap. It works fine.

```
New-AzCloudService  -Name $stagingName `
                -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
                -Location $location `
                -ConfigurationFile $cscfgFilePath `
                -DefinitionFile $csdefFilePath `
                -PackageFile $cspkgFilePath `
                -StorageAccount $storageAccount `
                -KeyVaultName $keyVaultName
```

I didn't find any samples or clues of how to add the "swappable cloud service" to the *New-AzCloudService*. I figured out there is such settings in
*NetworkProfile.SwappableCloudService.Id* but I can't understand how to set it up properly. For example, if I add:

```
      $production= Get-AzCloudService -ResourceGroup $resourceGroupName -CloudServiceName $productionName
      $production.NetworkProfile.SwappableCloudService.Id = $production.Name # just to reuse the object
      $loadBalancerConfig = CreateLoadBalancerConfig
      $networkProfile = @{loadBalancerConfiguration = $loadBalancerConfig; swappableCloudService = $production.NetworkProfile.SwappableCloudService }
            
        New-AzCloudService  -Name $stagingName `
                             ...
                      -NetworkProfile $networkProfile `
```

I got the error:

```
New-AzCloudService : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters
```

Is it possible to set the "swappable cloud service" for New-AzCloudService? How to do it?

Is it possible to set the "swappable cloud service" after the deploy (in any way, Azure portal, API, powershell, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the issue relates to the -NetworkProfile not being supported when `-ConfigurationFile`, `-DefinitionFile`, and `-PackageFile` are used.

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cloudservice/new-azcloudservice?view=azps-8.1.0), `-NetworkProfile` is used with `-PackageUrl` and `-Configuration` instead.

I've [asked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/951685/setting-a-swappable-cloud-service-when-using-new-a.html) Microsoft about this as I am having the same issue.

Comment: At the end I moved to New-AzResourceGroupDeployment instead.

Comment: Same, I suspect Microsoft is only doing the utmost minimum to support Cloud Services (Extended Support)

Answer (score 0):

Try `$production.Id` instead of `$production.Name`. Or `$production.id` (I am not sure if the case is important).